# Create a standard endnote reference using biblatex-chicago \cite styles within a footnote - possible?

Tags: footnotes, biblatex-chicago, endnotes

New to LaTeX (two weeks) but really liking it so far - able to create footnotes (symbolic references) and endnotes listed by chapter (numeric references) but not a normally structured endnote within the footnote using any of the `\cite` styles in the `biblatex-chicago` style, i.e.

[image: footnote with embedded endnote reference looking the way it should]

I *can* do so by just using `\endnote` but then the numbers come out wonky, plus it defeats the rather robust document management `biblatex-chicago` offers:

[image: footnote with embedded endnote and undesired expanded endnote text from chicago-biblatex \autocite command]

BTW have tried using other packages: `bigfoot`, `pagefoot`, `endnotez` but same results.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes,notetype=endonly,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}                           %footnotes
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}

\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\enoteheading{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
    \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
    \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
    \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}


\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexchapter*{#3}%
        \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
        \addtoendnotes{%
            \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
            {\unexpanded{#3}}}%
    }
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\latexchapter{#3}}
        {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
        \addtoendnotes{%
            \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
            {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
    }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter


\begin{document}
    
\frontmatter

\chapter*{Preface\markboth{PREFACE}{}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
    
Hello.\footnote{normal footnote} This\footnote{footnote with nested endnote\autocite{springer}} is a test.


\mainmatter
\chapter{One}

Third test.\footnote{third footnote, new chapter}
Endnote test\autocite{cicero}
    

\theendnotes

\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```

Though I would ask here before trying to craft my own scripts/macros, in case someone has already figured it out - or in case it's impossible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the following works, but does require adding a superscript numeral, which I do by way of the `\theendnote` counter, which I adjust using `newcommand \add` to adjust the superscript number to reflect any intervening endnotes between it and the footnote at the bottom of the page, i.e.

```
\newcommand{\add} [2] {\the\numexpr #1 + #2}
```

and creating a hidden citation in the main text using `\vphantom`

```
Hello.\footnote{normal footnote} This\footnote{footnote with nested endnote$^{\add{\theendnote}{2}}$} is a test.    %superscripted numeric reference

Endnote here\autocite{doody}                    %intervening endnote

\vphantom{\protect\autocite{springer}}          %hidden citation
```

Full code, showing formatting as intended as well as correctly ordered endnotes and bibliography:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a5paper,oneside]{memoir}

\usepackage[notes,notetype=endonly,isbn=false,doi=false,url=false,backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\usepackage[symbol]{footmisc}                           %footnotes
\renewcommand{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}

\usepackage{endnotes}
\counterwithin*{endnote}{chapter}

\let\latexchapter\chapter
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\enoteheading{%
    \setcounter{secnumdepth}{-2}
    \latexchapter*{\notesname\markboth{NOTES}{}}
    \mbox{}\par\vskip-\baselineskip
    \let\@afterindentfalse\@afterindenttrue
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{xparse}

\RenewDocumentCommand{\chapter}{som}{%
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\latexchapter*{#3}%
        \setcounter{endnote}{0}%
        \addtoendnotes{%
            \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
            {\unexpanded{#3}}}%
    }
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
        {\latexchapter{#3}}
        {\latexchapter[#2]{#3}}%
        \addtoendnotes{%
            \noexpand\enotedivision{\noexpand\subsection}
            {\chaptername\ \thechapter. \unexpanded{#3}}}%
    }%
}
\makeatletter
\def\enotedivision#1#2{\@ifnextchar\enotedivision{}{#1{#2}}}
\makeatletter


\newcommand{\add} [2] {\the\numexpr #1 + #2}    %adds two numbers, i.e. endnote counter and number of intervening references


\begin{document}
    
\frontmatter

\chapter*{Preface\markboth{PREFACE}{}}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Preface}
    
Hello.\footnote{normal footnote} This\footnote{footnote with nested endnote$^{\add{\theendnote}{2}}$} is a test.    %superscripted numeric reference

Endnote here\autocite{doody}                    %intervening endnote

\vphantom{\protect\autocite{springer}}          %hidden citation



\mainmatter
\chapter{One}

Third test.\footnote{third footnote, new chapter}
Endnote test\autocite{cicero}
    

\theendnotes

\printbibliography
    
\end{document}
```